# What is the right way to set JS and CSS paths in express/jade file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to create my first application using Mongo, NodeJS, Express and Sequelize.
If I use `link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://localhost:3000/css/style.min.css')`everything works fine, but, is it the right way?

How to get the app path (or something like) to use in layout and views files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use an absolute path, so you dont include the server name

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.min.css')
```

Answer (score 3):

In your main file (probably `app.js`) you need to set your public directory - I usually name the directory "public," and you should put it in the app's root.  Here's the code to do that:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Then, to serve your css folder, you can put it in the public directory and use the path `/css/style.min.css`.

For your jade files, create a folder called `views` in your app's root.  Then, add this to your `app.js`.

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

Put all of your jade files in there.  Now, if you have a `layout.jade` in there and you want to use it in `index.jade`, you can use the layout's path relative to the view directory to reference it, for example:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 stuff here
```